# Carregar post sem refresh da página com AJAX e JQUERY

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Estou precisando de uma ajuda em Wordpress pois eu gostaria de carregar `posts` sem `refresh` ou `reload` da página. Tenho um menu que retorna posts de uma determinada categoria em uma `<div>` a esquerda e gostaria de conseguir carregar na `<div>` a direita o conteúdo referente ao hyperlink que foi clicado. Além do mais, isto está dentro de uma fancybox, motivo pelo qual não pode haver reload. A estrutura HTML é esta:

```
<div id="floatpost" role="main"> 
  <!-- section -->
  <section>
    <div class="rReleases">
      <div id="menu" class="rPosts">
        <ul>
            <?php
                $recent = new WP_Query("cat=7");
                while ($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
            ?>
            <li>
              <p class="title">
                <?php the_time('j / m'); ?> - <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
              </p>
            </li>
            <?php
                endwhile;
            ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="content" class="rPost">

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- /section --> 
</div>
```

Comment: É bem diferente, está em um contexto totalmente diferente.

Answer (score 4):

Acho que é isso o que você precisa:

```
$('#menu a').on('click', function () {
  /* to-do: mostrar ao usuário que há conteúdo sendo carregado
  se não o ele irá clicar novamente pensando que ocorreu um erro */

  // carrega o conteúdo
  $('#content').load(this.href);

  // evita que o link seja aberto normalmente
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
  $('#content').load(this.href);
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Poderia dar uma explicação sobre o código?

Comment: É a mesma coisa do meu: usar `return false` no jQuery é exatamente igual a usar `evt.stopPropagation(); evt.preventDefault();`... não, há uma diferença, o seletor é outro: esse pode acabar dando problemas com outros elementos.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer só carregar o conteúdo da página e exibir ao lado:

```
        $(document).ready(function(e) {

            $('#menu-lateral .post').click(function(e){
                var page = $(this).attr('href');

                $('#janela-direita').html('');

                $('#janela-direita').load(page, function(x, y, z){
                    $('#janela-direita').trigger('create');
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```