# Como executar um script PHP sem refresh com jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

Se vocês acessarem este site [GCMC Advocacia](http://gcmc.com.br/site/) poderão perceber que o menu só mudará de idioma se clicar duas vezes seguidas na bandeira. Isso porque a página não está executando o script que carrega o menu de acordo com idioma da primeira vez. Eu imagino que seja alguma coisa relacionada a jQuery e AJAX, mas não tenho experiência suficiente para fazer o script. Podem me ajudar por favor?

Estou usando este código PHP:

```
$en = explode("/", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); $idioma = $en[4];
```

É ele que troca o idioma estourando a url e detectando se a string `'/en/'` se encontra na url fazendo assim que o menu troque de idioma. Preciso executar o script PHP realmente a cada refresh permitindo assim a troca imediata do menu.

Comment: Essas informações não são suficientes para alguém conseguir te ajudar. Por que você acha que está relacionado a Ajax e/ou jQuery? Os links de idioma parecem links comuns, que não usam ajax. É possível que você tenha um problema de lógica no seu PHP (gerando o menu antes de redefinir o idioma).

Comment: Esta pergunta é a mesma desta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6299/carregar-post-sem-refresh-da-pagina-com-ajax-e-jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente trocar `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` por `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` é a variável que armazena o endereço dá página que enviou o usuário para a página atual, por isso que funciona no segundo clique.

Comment: Parabéns "IGROSSITER" por simplesmente tentar ajudar !!!

Comment: vlw, tamos ai! ^^

Answer (score 1):

AJAX com jQuery é extremamente simples, segue um exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "teste.html",
  cache: false
})
  .done(function( html ) {
    $( "#resultados" ).append( html ); // Ou qualquer outra comando com o resultado que é 'html'
  });
```

Infelizmente eu não posso resolver o seu problema especificamente, dê uma lida sobre JavaScript e jQuery, que vai ser muito fácil caso já programe em alguma linguagem.

Alguns links:

[Javascript Tutorial](http://www.javascript-tutorial.com.br/content-2.html)

[jQuery em W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jQuery/)

Comment: Ok, mas com as informações que temos não é sequer possível dizer se o problema tem a ver com ajax ou jQuery...

Comment: Concordo plenamente